# Two projects with same dll, Cast issue

Tags: c#, dll, control-library

Hi fellow programmers,

I'm creating a ControlLibrary for future project's that uses the amazing MaterialDesignXaml library. In this ControlLib I use the MaterialDesignThemes.dll that contains several styled controls, resources and classes.

Now my problem is that I need to use the same dll's in the real application (sae sollution for now). If I want to use the mentioned control library in this project (as project reference) I always get this error:
[Dll Error in Application Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRIZ2.jpg)
.

I understand the problem the compiler has with this, since It cannot check if two refrences (from seperate projects in the sollution) are the same dll. But how can I fix this?

The strange thing is that the designer complains like in the screenshot, but the application runs just fine...

I'm using TortoiseSVN for Version Management, maybe this has to do something with it?

Any idea's?

Comment: Is target framework same for your application and for the MaterialDesignXaml library?

Comment: The library and application are the same, but I'm not sure how to find the framework of the MaterialDesign dll

Comment: Not sure if I checked the correct Git repository [MaterialDesignXaml](https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.csproj) but the target framework is v4.5.

Comment: I will test to set my projects to V4.5 too, thanks for the tip!